# 'conda list', 'conda --version', and 'conda install' do not work

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda

I get a troublesome problem.

My `pip` and `python` of `/home/xxx/local/anacoda2/bin` all works, but `conda` does not still work. When I input `conda list` or `conda --version` and `conda install xxx` in my ubuntu16.04  terminal, it shows nothing. Why?

can anyone give some advises? thank you very much~

Answer (score -1):

You maybe don't export the path of acnaconda to your environment, you can try this:

```
export PATH=/home/xxx/local/anacoda2/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: wait, what did you put instead of /opt/Ana... ?

Comment: I did `export PATH=/home/xxx/local/anacoda2/bin:$PATH`, and do `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: So, what did you get?

Comment: When I input `conda list` or `conda --version` and `conda install xxx` in my ubuntu16.04 terminal, it shows nothing

Comment: could you put `python` in your terminal, and shere the out put ?

Comment: it's wierd, could you pls share a pic of terminal to your question